# linear transformation proof $T(a(j))=b(j)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a(1),\ldots,a(n)$ within $R^n$ and let $A$ be the matrix whose $j$-th column is $a(j).$ If $A$ is an invertible matrix, prove that for every choice of $b(1),\ldots,b(n)$ within $R^n$ there exists a linear transformation $T$ from $R^n$ into $R^n$ such that $T(a(j))=b(j)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is invertible, we have that all the $n\times 1$ vectors $a(1),\ldots,a(n)$ are linearly independent and they also span $\mathbb R^n$. Thus, every vector $b(i),i= 1,\ldots, n$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors $a(1),\ldots, a(n)$. More specifically, we can write the vector $b(j)$ as:
$$b(j) = C_{1j} a(1) + C_{2j}a(2) + \cdots +C_{nj}a(n).$$ 
We can consider the matrix $C$ as the matrix representation of the linear transformation $T$ and it holds:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
a(1) & a(2) & \cdots & a(n)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots
\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
C_{11} & C_{12} & \cdots & C_{1n}\\
C_{21} & C_{22} & \cdots & C_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots\\
C_{n1} & C_{n2} & \cdots & C_{nn}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
b(1) & b(2) & \cdots & b(n)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this concept

Comment: You are welcome!!